# lua can't unwind exception, generated by luaL_error on hp-ux

Tags: exception, lua

I have a problem with lua... on hp-ux 11.31
I have a lua-script that call some function that has been written on C++.
In that function luaL_error is called... but application crashed then luaL_error is called, because exception isn't unwind by lua...
On other platforms this application is work correct.

Do you have any idea what may be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to compile the Lua library as a C++ library, instead of a C library. Then Lua will use C++ exceptions instead of longjmps.

Comment: My lua library has been alrady compiled as C++ library.

Comment: @user2025098, perhaps you could post a minimal example show the problem and let the C++ experts look at it.